# Load all images inside a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-loading

I am loading 52 images that share the same class, when printing the loaded images to the console the amount of images that are outputting change each time I refresh.

The desired output would be to load **every** image in the class, as I am trying to tracking the progress with a progress bar then display the image gallery.

```
var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbImg");
var thumbTotal = thumbs.length;
console.log("number of thumbImg's = ", thumbTotal);

$(".thumbImg").on("load", function() {
    console.log("the following has loaded = ",this);
});
```

This outputs the following showing the random amount of images loaded.

[image: 1/2]

[image: 2/2]

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but getElementsByClassName returns a "live" node list. This means that it doesn't actually query for the nodes at the point of the getElementsByClassName call. It queries each and every time you reference the node list returned by the call. This allows you to always have a node list that represents the current nodes that match the class name, even if new nodes have been added AFTER the initial call. Try changing getElementsByClass name to querySelectorAll("theClassName").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be due to browser caching. You can try checking each image's `.complete` property, and run the code immediately if already complete.

```
$(".thumbImg").each(function(i, el) {
  if (el.complete) {
    handler.call(el);
  } else {
    $(el).on("load", handler);
  }
})

function handler() {
    console.log("the following has loaded = ",this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of browser caching. Thumbs up!